# Transpose static range in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, transpose

I've tried to transpose a static range from column A on sheet 1 to rows on sheet 3 in a loop, to no avail. Here is the code I'm using so far:

```
Sub Looptranspose()
'
' Looptranspose Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+a

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    x = 1
    y = x + 18
    Range("A" & CStr(x) & ":A" & CStr(y)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    x = x + 19
End Sub
```

How do I loop this until row A is complete? This code transposes the selected 1st range of 19 cells in column A into a selected row on Sheet 3.

I need macro to select next 19 cells in row A on sheet one and transpose into next row on sheet 3. Here's the example:

Excel Step 1
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2TQdtpfUIa5OUpRTWNwLUQ5WVk/edit?usp=sharing

Excel Step 2
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2TQdtpfUIa5TkNrVXRwOHh2TFk/edit?usp=sharing

How can I continue selecting following 19 cells in row A  Sheet 1 (until there is no more data) and transposing to following row in sheet 3?

Comment: why do you need to loop one by one? i can't see your worksheet, browser incompatible. :) Can't you have it in one go?

Comment: I think you have your terms jumbled up. `A` is most definitely not a row. If you rephrase your question, I'm sure I can help out. I don't see anything complicated here, but you have to be clearer. Also, can't access Google Drive on work so... better if clearer explanation is given. Anyway, let me take a shot: Basically, in Column A, you have 19 rows you want to transpose to the next empty row in Sheet3, is that it? And you want to go on until there are no more in A? Is the row count of the data in A always divisible by 19? :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Floris helped me out below. A lot of good ideas here. I'm not a programmer but you have to start somewhere, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code and the screen shots, I think you want to take a long column A in one sheet, and transpose it in 19-cell chunks into another sheet.

The problem is - you don't actually include a loop, and you don't update the location of the destination. I tried fixing those things in my example. If that is not what you wanted, please leave a comment.

Note - typically using `.Select` will make your code slow, hard to read, and prone to errors. It is better to create objects that reference specific ranges.

```
Sub copyChunk()
' copy chunks of 19 cells from column A of sheet 1
' and paste their transpose on sheet 3
' starting in the first row

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Dim chunk As Integer
chunk = 19

Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3")

' picking the starting point here - this could be "anywhere"
Set r1 = Range(sh1.Cells(1, 1), sh1.Cells(chunk, 1))
Set r2 = sh2.[A1]

While Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(r1) > 0
  r1.Copy
  r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
  ' move down "chunk" cells for the source
  Set r1 = r1.Offset(chunk, 0)
  ' move down one row for the destination
  Set r2 = r2.Offset(1, 0)
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Floris, this did exactly what I needed and there's no loop, go figure. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. It took a little bit of guessing but the screen shots helped. Not sure what you mean with "there's no loop". In your code, or in my code...?